# Select all none null values from all columns in a table

Tags: mysql, sql

I am having an issue going through column by column and getting a count of all the non-null values in each column.  I think issue is how I am getting the column names.  In the last select statement where I am trying to select all of the values in each column, I am just getting the column name as many times as there are rows.  Any idea on how to fix this?

```
DECLARE @cnt INT = 1;

WHILE @cnt < (SELECT COUNT(*)
                FROM mySchema.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
                WHERE table_name = 'tblName') + 1
BEGIN
    DECLARE @column varchar(9) = (select column_name
    FROM mySchema.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
    WHERE table_name = 'tblName'
    AND ordinal_position = @cnt);

    SELECT @column 
        FROM [mySchema].[dbo].[tblName]
        WHERE @column is not null
        AND @column <> ''

        SET @cnt = @cnt + 1;
    END;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

select @variable will just return you a value of variable. You need to use some dynamic SQL I believe. Maybe smth like exec('select ' + @colname + ' from ' etc) will work for you (at least it will work in MS SQL server).

Comment: This worked out perfectly, thank you.  Good way to put the Exec to work.

Answer (score 0):

Not absolutely sure but why can't you directly do like

```
SELECT column1, column2,column3
    FROM [mySchema].[dbo].[tblName]
    WHERE column1 is not null
    AND column2 is not null
    AND column3 is not null
```

Comment: I am trying to write a sql script for use on any table, that is why I was trying to leave out the column names.